# AreYouSure jquery plugin does not show error message if partial postback happens

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

We have a page with all the controls inside a Update Panel. If any data changes inside the form and user tries to leave the page without saving then he gets a warning message.

There is a DropDownList with AutoPostBack=true inside UpdatePanel.
Whenever selection changes on this dropdown, `areyousure` does not work.

**Code**

```
$('#form1').areyousure();
```

How could this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You should have below script at the end of page,

```
$('#form1').areyousure();

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $('#form1').areyousure();
}
```

Comment: Any javascript error you received? Please check in javascript console.

Comment: is there any BeginRequest function also?

Comment: Can you please verify form id is `form1`? Also verify it works first time and stop working after postback? If so, can you please add alert statement at both places and make sure you receive an alert when you make postback?

Comment: I think you misunderstood! It works first time, second time and so on but only if we try to navigate or leave the page. In case if it is a partial postback then it won't work. Even after partial postback if we try to navigate without saving it will work.

Comment: Let me clear it, $('#form1').areyousure(); is not working after partial postback, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105641/discussion-between-kamalpreet-and-piyush-khatri).